# Where and when do I use these lures [new fisher]

Tags: gear, fishing, fishing-tackle, technique, bait

This is my assortment of lures/bait:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(The can is Gulp! Earthworms)

I went fishing and caught my first fish today with the golden spoon in the red box to the 2nd far right (below the daredevil-looking spoon).
It was too small so I let it go again.

**I'm interested in the following fish:**

- Pike
- Crucian carps
- Trout
- Brasen
- Tench

Can you name me in what kind of scenario I'd use each of my lures and for what type of fish?

Comment: Too many questions in a single post would suit the website better being separated into several questions, just a note.

Comment: Rephrased the question.

Answer (score 5):

The first picture is of **spinners**. you tow them though the water and they spin and sparkle, attracting the attention of predatory fish. Use these where you have good visibility in the water. The different sizes colours will depend on what fish you want to catch.

The second set are **lures**. Again designed to be pulled though the water but slower. these are designed to look like fish swiming. Again good visibility needed for these.

The above will only catch fish that are predatory. e.g. Pike

---

The third picture are **floats**. This is for a different type of fishing altogether. I.e. baited line fishing. The float is designed to sit in the water with a hook attached underneath with some bait on it. Best in calm water. Visibility less of an issue, the fish are attracted to the bait by smell mostly.

I'm not familiar with the **Gulp worms**. They appears to be some kind of artificial bait. You will likely want to use these with the floats, etc.

The above target fish that scavenge mostly rather than hunt actively. Though a degree of cross over is expected. i.e. trout

---

A degree of trail and error will likely be needed when you start out. It very much depends on local conditions, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You do need to rephrase the question better, but I can still provide this answer.

Pike will go after anything that bass will. Spinners, plugs, jerk baits, Texas rigged worms, etc etc. just about anything so long as it within reach.

Trout need a more gentle approach, the Mepps style lures and perhaps the gulp worms are your best bet for trout. Real worms too left to rest on the bottom behind a big rock.